# Modulo on negative index while accessing data gets wrong

Tags: java, modulo

I want to store a two-dimensional world, consisting of Blocks (having an x and an y coordinate) who are grouped in Chunks (having an x and an y coordinate).

This code shows how a chunk groups some blocks:

```
public class Chunk {

    Block[][] blocks = new Block[GameProperties.MAP_SIZE_CHUNK][GameProperties.MAP_SIZE_CHUNK];
    int xpos, ypos;
    public Chunk(int posx, int posy){
        this.xpos = posx;
        this.ypos = posy;
        for (int x = 0; x < blocks.length; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < blocks.length; y++) {
                int blockx = xpos*GameProperties.MAP_SIZE_CHUNK + x;
                int blocky = ypos*GameProperties.MAP_SIZE_CHUNK + y;
                blocks[x][y] = new Block(blockx, blocky);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

At the moment **GameProperties.MAP_SIZE_CHUNK** = 8, so each Chunk represents 8x8 = 64 Blocks but this is content to change and i have to do it dynamically!

Coordinates are Integers and can be positive and negative.

> -100 >= y > MAXINT
>   -MAXINT > x > MAXINT

Chunk-coordinates have the same rules but are counted from the left-top Block:

> Chunk (0|0) = 0 <= x/y < 8
>   Chunk (-1|0) = -8 <= x/y < 0

This is how I calculate chunk and relative Block from Block-Coordinates:

```
public int modulo(int a, int b){
    if(a < 0){
        return (a % b + b) % b;
    }
    return a % b;
}

public Block getBlock(int x, int y){
    int chunkx;
    int blockx;
    if(x < 0){
        int xn = x-GameProperties.MAP_SIZE_CHUNK;
        if(xn > GameProperties.MAP_SIZE_CHUNK){
            xn--;
        }
        chunkx = (xn)/GameProperties.MAP_SIZE_CHUNK;
        blockx = modulo((xn),GameProperties.MAP_SIZE_CHUNK);
    }else{
        chunkx = x/GameProperties.MAP_SIZE_CHUNK;
        blockx = modulo(x,GameProperties.MAP_SIZE_CHUNK);
    }

    int chunky;
    int blocky;
    if(y < 0){
        chunky = y/GameProperties.MAP_SIZE_CHUNK;
        if(chunky == 0){
            chunky = -1;
        }
        blocky = modulo(y,GameProperties.MAP_SIZE_CHUNK);
    }else{
        chunky = y/GameProperties.MAP_SIZE_CHUNK;
        blocky = modulo((y),GameProperties.MAP_SIZE_CHUNK);
    }
    Chunk c = getChunk(chunkx, chunky);
    Block b = c.getRelativeBlock(blockx, blocky);
    System.out.println("<<< " + x + " | " + b.getxPos() + "   = " + (x-b.getxPos()));
    return b;
}
```

To be fair it is a real mess since I have tried about everything to get the modulo working on negative numbers...
Sometimes, the Chunk (-1|0) gets to position (0|0) sometimes, Chunks with x<-1 get moved one block. I have thought of it quite long but have gotten blind for the problem, can you help?

GetChunk and Chunk.getRelativeBlock are fully functional and are simply returning placed Blocks/Chunks from Map/Array.

**EDIT**

Since it was unclear what I was asking:
I had problems with negative modulos in Java. But even yet there is something wrong in the end-result, it could be the modulo-function and it could be somewhere else. 
**Does someone know where my problem with my code it?**

Comment: What exactly is the problem? It looks like your `modulo` method does what you need (gives the positive mod).

Comment: That is, what are the inputs and results that are not what you are expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use this:

```
public int modulo(int a, int b){
    if(a < 0){
        return (a + b) % b;
    }
    return a % b;
}
```

instead of this:

```
public int modulo(int a, int b){
    if(a < 0){
        return (a % b + (1 + (Math.abs(a) / b)) * b) % b;
    }
    return a % b;
}
```

Another question: how do you know that b is positive?

Comment: b is positive 8 every time.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Let me know whether this is more helpful.

Comment: I have some problems somewhere else in my logic. I have accepted your answer. The modulo i had from the beginning was working well, i simply used it wrong...